# mysql copy into log

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table, it has about 97 row and 5 columns of data.

I'd like to copy all this into a text file, then delete all the data, but leave the table intact.  Whats the best way to do this in an automated way?

Comment: to do a automatic backup look http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html

Comment: @Haim Evgi - you should undelete your answer, it may be what the asker is looking for. (mysqldump is not as read-friendly as CSV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to save csv file you can run this query :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mytable.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

to delete all data from the table add this line

```
TRUNCATE mytable;
```

put it in a sql file and run it in a cron job, look on my link(point number 2) in the comments

Comment: Thank you haim.  What is /tmp/mytables.csv relative to?  Is it possible to make it relative to the php file that runs the command?

Comment: i dont try to run it from php, you can try it, have a good luck

Answer (score 2):

To dump the data:

`mysqldump -uUserName -pPassword dbName tableName > log.sql` ([reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html))

To empty the table:

`TRUNCATE tableName;` ([reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html))